# Variable Won't Update In Class

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 900
        self.win = pygame.display.set_mode([self.width, self.height])
        self.caption = pygame.display.set_caption('Clicker Game','Game')
        self.money = 0 
        self.moneyperclick = 0

    def moneytracker(self):
        self.money = self.money + self.moneyperclick
        print(self.money)

    def mousestuff(self):
        self.mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    def mainloop(self):
        self.mousestuff()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.moneytracker()
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            pygame.display.update()

while True:
    Game().mainloop()
```

I'm still somewhat new to coding but I am very confused as to why the `self.money` variable isn't updating even though I call for it to update. I've done some tests and I know that it is looping the code where I set `self.money = 0` but I don't know how to get around this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
while True:
    Game().mainloop()
```

This creates a new `Game` object in every iteration of the loop, which means all the values are initialized for the first time, because it's a new object.

Alternatives are to move the `while True` loop inside `mainloop()`, or try something like:

```
game = Game()
while True:
    game.mainloop()
```

This creates a single `Game` object as `game`, whose `mainloop()` method is called repeatedly. Because the object is only created once, the attributes of the object (e.g. `money`, accessed as `self.money`) that are modified as a result of player actions will keep their values between iterations of the loop.

In the original loop structure, a new `Game` object was created each time, which means that a player's actions were only performed once before the object was abandoned and replaced by a new one, with newly initialized attributes.

Comment: Can you explain why the 
game = Game()
while True:
    game.mainloop()

actually works?

Comment: @Happyface456: I added some more detail